# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'. in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have problem with my SQL Server query:

```
UPDATE latihan AS t1 ,
       (SELECT Equipment, system_status, functloc 
        FROM latihan 
        WHERE system_status='ESTO') AS t2 
SET t1.functloc = t2.functloc
WHERE t1.supereq = t2.equipment
```

I just want update the `functloc` on equipment based `functloc` on `supereq`.

The error is:

> [Err] 42000 - [SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.
>   42000 - [SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
update t1 set
  functloc = t2.functloc
from latihan t1
inner join (
  select Equipment, system_status, functloc
  from latihan
  where system_status='ESTO'
) t2 on t2.equipment = t1.supereq
```